# Magento: How to replace all {{example var="something"}} with actual data?

Tags: magento

I’m working on custom feed generation. 
All logic is in model. This Model called by cron by schedule.

The problem I’m facing is that in description content data like `{{store url}}`, `{{config path="trans_email/ident_sales/email"}}`, `{{customVar code=phone}}`, etc.

Could anyone tell how to properly replace these variables in model?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Mage::getModel('core/email_template_filter')->filter($description);
```

Some variables are Magento variables, like store_url, but you can add your own to filter:

```
Mage::getModel('core/email_template_filter')->setVariables(array('custom_url' => Mage::getUrl('*/*/custom'), 'custom_var' => 100))->filter($description);
```